# AngularJS broken JQuery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm a new angularjs student, and i was making my menu with ng-repeat.
I made a template too, but when i debug my code, all jquery animations are gone. All menus are inside of my div's with jquery animations.

```
            <nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">

                 <webapi class="nav metismenu sidebar-collapse"></webapi>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

This is my HTML, the repeat with a template only works with bootstrap CSS style, but all animations are gone.
Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks a lot!

https://plnkr.co/edit/BCmH9wnXXQzd7wntsrZl?p=preview

Comment: What is the jquery code?

Comment: Here you are: https://plnkr.co/edit/BCmH9wnXXQzd7wntsrZl?p=preview

Comment: You have to download it, i dont know why Plunker does not build it... i think its because there are much code...
So, that's what i want to do. this animation broken when i use directives and ng-repeat on AngularJS.
When i created the template of <li>'s , i put it between Nav's and all classes of Inspinia.JS and Metismenu. but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plunk doesn't work because you're mixing `http` and `https`. The insecure content (jQuery and the font) is blocked.

I updated your code to reference `https`, commented out the missing plugins, added in AngularJS 1.5 for the existing menu items so you should be able to compare that with your attempt:

https://plnkr.co/edit/IunNO1j4mvueK6BawPa5?p=preview

Comment: Hmmm Got it! But why it does not work in google chrome? i tested in firefox and it goes well. 

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the developer console in Chrome and check for any error messages

Comment: I substitute the jquery link to a file, and it works well.
So... I can't mix Http and Https? Angular uses Https, so thats why you change all http to https, right?